# How to display data from json retrieved from django-rest-framework?

Tags: json, django, rest, angular, django-rest-framework

I've cloned [tour of heroes tutorial product](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes) from angular team where demo data is storing in `in-memory-data-service.ts`. Since my preferred backend is django-rest-framework, I need to link them together.

For example, my heroes are translating from localhost:8000/api/v1/heroes/.

```
  [
    {
        "name": "Greg",
        "id": 5,
    },
    {
        "name": "Krek",
        "id": 6,
    }
]
```

What should I do except removing `in-memory-data-service.ts` to replace heroes list with provided by django backend via json? It would be great if you'll tell me do I need model declaration

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

yet if rest-framework gives me full objects structure stored in JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consume any REST API you have to write a service like below,

```
 import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
 import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

 export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
 }

 @Injectable()
 export class HeroService {
   constructor(private _http: Http) { }

   getHeroes() {
     return this._http.get('api/v1/heroes')
      .map((response: Response) => <Hero []>response.json())
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!!